# Count the hit rate of an image being loaded in PHP / JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Suppose I have two HTML file as below, whenever user click on the button, the test.gif will be loaded. I want to ask how can I count the image of test.gif is being loaded in PHP / JavaScript?

Thanks

1.html

```
<input type="button" onclick="example()" value="Click Me!" />
<div id="placeholder">
  <p>Placeholding text</p>
</div>

<script>
function example() {
  $('#placeholder').load("2.html");
}
</script>
```

2.html

```
<img src="test.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In `2.html` you can increase with `JavaScript` some value stored in `COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

For ALL access (not only the particular user who currently load the page), the easiest part *if you have access to server log* is:

```
exec("grep 'GET /test.gif' /var/log/apache2/access.log|wc -l", $result);
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load a php script instead of 2.html which echoes just the same, but then you could do some counting there. If you just want to show the number in the page you could also increment a global counter var in the function. Of course what silent wrote is also possible but this is the total count, not only from this function.